# What is a Dofen Akuma?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, sukkah, masechet-sukkah

The gemara in Sukka 4 speaks of Dofen Akuma (literally a "bent wall"). How does this halacha look/work?

Comment: https://www.mishnahyomit.com/articles/Sukkah/Dofen%20Akuma

Comment: https://steinsaltz.org/daf/sukka17/ https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/holidays/halakhot-sukka-construction

Comment: Not everyone translates akuma as bent. Some rishonim say it means move (we look at the wall like it moved). Cf. עקימת שפתים

Comment: Please [edit] to specify what you don't understand about the concept after learning the daf. Motion to close as unclear in the meantime

Answer (score 3):

[image: Drawing from Peirush Chai]

If there are less than 4 amos of invalid sechach (but not air) between the top of the wall and the valid sechach, halocho lemoshe misinai considers the invalid sechach as an extension of the wall (dofen akumah = bent wall) and the sukkah remains kosher although one cannot use the sukkah under the invalid sechach. (see [here](https://www.mishnahyomit.com/articles/Sukkah/Dofen%20Akuma) for more details.)